# Is ICC unable to optimize away simple and idiomatic constructs?

Tags: c++, optimization, icc

```
bool f1(int value) { return value % 2 == 0; }
bool f2(int value) { return ! (value & 1); }
```

Those two functions do the same thing, and I expect from a decent compiler to produce the same assembly for both of them.

#### [GCC 7 with `-O2`](https://godbolt.org/g/XJcyxw):

```
f1(int):
        mov     eax, edi
        not     eax
        and     eax, 1
        ret
f2(int):
        mov     eax, edi
        not     eax
        and     eax, 1
        ret
```

#### [clang 5 with `-O2`](https://godbolt.org/g/54r6uu):

```
f1(int):                                 # @f1(int)
        test    dil, 1
        sete    al
        ret
f2(int):                                 # @f2(int)
        test    dil, 1
        sete    al
        ret
```

#### [icc 18 with `-O2`](https://godbolt.org/g/oXGWHS):

```
f1(int):
        and       edi, -2147483647                              #1.37
        jge       ..B1.4        # Prob 50%                      #1.37
        sub       edi, 1                                        #1.37
        or        edi, -2                                       #1.37
        inc       edi                                           #1.37
..B1.4:                         # Preds ..B1.1 ..B1.5
        xor       eax, eax                                      #1.42
        cmp       edi, 1                                        #1.42
        setb      al                                            #1.42
        ret                                                     #1.42
f2(int):
        not       edi                                           #3.40
        and       edi, 1                                        #3.40
        mov       eax, edi                                      #3.40
        ret                                                     #3.40
```

(`-O3` doesn't help).

So, is icc not a decent compiler? is it right to discriminate the two implementations for some specific corner case I didn't anticipate? Do I need to get my expectations lower about what a decent compiler can do?

Comment: strangely if the parameter is `unsigned` it will generate for `f1` the same code you see in `f2` https://godbolt.org/g/jJvKPq

Comment: @bolov Not that strangely, IMO, given that for signed ints, `i % 2` can produce three distinct values (-1, 0, and 1). But ICC doesn't realise that the distinction between -1 and 1 is irrelevant when the result is compared to 0.

Comment: and to answer your (off-topic opinion-based) question: judging a compiler just by 1 (artificial, not even impactfull) case of optimization is just... Pick any compiler. Pick any software for that matter. And you will surely find 1 case where it doesn't perform optimal. That's the nature of human-written software. When AI takes over the world and there will be AI-written software then maybe things will change. But I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: @bolov: What should be far more important than performance is whether a compiler generates code that behaves usefully in all cases required by a piece of software.  From what I can tell, the only way to make gcc or clang behave as well as icc in that regard is to disable many optimizations.